# jQuery replace entire table elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this table

```
<table><tbody><tr><th><br></th></tr></tbody></table>
```

on multimple pages, and I can't remove them from database. 
So I want to remove this entire line with jquery. I can't add a class or id to remove it like that.

This is why I need a replace this table with nothing, like

```
var elem = elem.replace('table...','');
```

any help please? thanks.

Comment: `$('table').remove()`

Comment: no. i need to get this somehow in a var or something

Comment: whats wrong with your approach? `document.documentElement.innerHtml.replace('<table><tbody><tr><th><br></th></tr></tbody></table>','');`

Comment: @Banana this is not jquery.. i need same thing in jquery

Comment: Why not just hide it with CSS?

Comment: @AdrianAxinte uhm, i dont really see why you insist on using jQuery, as its not a different language its simply an extension library for Javascript, but you could do a `$(document).html().replace('<table><tbody><tr><th><br></th></tr‌​></tbody></table>','');`

Answer (score 2):

can't you just use one of:

```
$('table').remove(); // remove from dom
```

or

```
$('table').hide();  // hide the table, but stays in dom
```

Comment: somethime I have multiple tables in same place, so i can't just say remove first/last table

Comment: @AdrianAxinte - You'll need to identify something that will you to uniquely identify the table, even without a class or ID. E.g. a unique ancestor, sibling, etc.

Comment: @j08691 yes, but how? like i said, once it's first table, than can be 3rd table or last..

Comment: @AdrianAxinte - We'd need to see more of the code you're dealing with.